# A very active (new) user suddenly disappeared. What happened?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Since yesterday, a new user started contributing on PSE. This user was very active and apparently very eager about physics and I answered one of their questions. The user was active until a few hours ago! Now we see that its profile was deleted. As far as I know, after confirming the profile deletion by user, the account is scheduled to be deleted in 24 hours. What happened for this user? If the user intended to delete their account, why was he/she so active?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

User accounts can be deleted for two reasons:

- Deletion is requested by the user while logged in
- Moderators delete an account because it is used to violate a site policy as a [sock puppet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sock_puppet_account). Examples include multiple accounts created by the same user to upvote their main account, or accounts created by a currently suspended user to circumvent their suspension.

We generally do not disclose information about specific account deletions beyond what is already publicly visible (i.e. nothing, currently).

Comment: Spammers also get nuked from orbit, and perhaps a few other particular violations, right?

Comment: @JonCuster Indeed, this isn't an exhaustive list, I've just listed the two examples for moderator deletion that occur most frequently.